# ASP.Net Boilerplate & jTable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, boilerplate

I have studied the ASP.Net boilderplate template (http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates)  and made some custom changes. 
I have a "GetComponentDataList()" method in my services. I played around with that and rendered it as a list like shown here:

```
 <!-- Component list    -->
 <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="component in vm.components">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <br />
        <span>Entry:</span>
        <span>{{component.entry}}</span>
    </div>
 </ul>
```

components.js code:

```
vm.refreshComponents = function () {
            abp.ui.setBusy( //Set whole page busy until getComponentDataList complete
               null,
               componentDataService.getComponentDataList( //Call application service method directly from javascript
               ).success(function (data) {
                   vm.components = data.componentData;
               })

           );
        };
```

Now I would like to render the components via jTable. jTable expects an action to get the list of data:

```
listAction: '/api/services/app/componentData/GetComponentDataList',
```

How do I use jTable from boilerplate template?

```
     1. Do I need to add a method in my "HomeController" to use jTable?
     2. The result of my "GetComponentDataList" method in my service is of type IOutputDto.
        That means the result of my service is not directly a list. There is one indirection
        level inbetween. Seems like this does not fit together.
     3. Can I provide a function in my JS-ViewModel and use that function instead of an action URL?
```

Any hint would be awesome.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a sample project to work ABP with jTable. I did not finish it yet. But you can check it. https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/AbpWithjTable

Add abp.jtable.js to your file (https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/AbpWithjTable/AbpjTable.Web/App/Main/libs/abp.jtable.js) after all ABP and jtable scripts.

See example js: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/AbpWithjTable/AbpjTable.Web/App/Main/views/people/people.js

See example C# App service: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/AbpWithjTable/AbpjTable.Application/People/PersonAppService.cs

Comment: this link are broken and I don't see any example using jtable in the abp sample project. Do we have to consider abp.jtable deprecated?